# can anyone tell why $auth_url is going blank in this code?

Tags: php, contacts, yahoo

My code is given below: I'm trying to use this code to import yahoo contacts in which I've given the app_id, callback url, customer id and customer secret. I don't understand why the link is creating pop ups with the same url. May be it is due to $auth_url, Can anyone help what i'm missing?
    FILE).'/lib/Yahoo.inc';

```
//for converting xml to array
function XmltoArray($xml) {
        $array = json_decode(json_encode($xml), TRUE);

        foreach ( array_slice($array, 0) as $key => $value ) {
            if ( empty($value) ) $array[$key] = NULL;
            elseif ( is_array($value) ) $array[$key] = XmltoArray($value);
        }

        return $array;
    }

// debug settings
//error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE); # do not show notices as library is php4 compatable
//ini_set('display_errors', true);
YahooLogger::setDebug(true);
YahooLogger::setDebugDestination('LOG');

// use memcache to store oauth credentials via php native sessions
//ini_set('session.save_handler', 'files');
//session_save_path('/tmp/');
session_start();

// Make sure you obtain application keys before continuing by visiting:
// https://developer.yahoo.com/dashboard/createKey.html

define('OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY', '****');
define('OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET', '****');
define('OAUTH_DOMAIN', '*****');
define('OAUTH_APP_ID', '****');

if(array_key_exists("logout", $_GET)) {
  // if a session exists and the logout flag is detected
  // clear the session tokens and reload the page.
  YahooSession::clearSession();
  header("Location: index.php");
}

// check for the existance of a session.
// this will determine if we need to show a pop-up and fetch the auth url,
// or fetch the user's social data.
$hasSession = YahooSession::hasSession(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_APP_ID);

if($hasSession == FALSE) {
  // create the callback url,
  $callback = YahooUtil::current_url()."?in_popup";
$sessionStore = new NativeSessionStore();
  // pass the credentials to get an auth url.
  // this URL will be used for the pop-up.
  $auth_url = YahooSession::createAuthorizationUrl(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, $callback, $sessionStore);



}
else {
  // pass the credentials to initiate a session
  $session = YahooSession::requireSession(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_APP_ID);

  // if the in_popup flag is detected,
  // the pop-up has loaded the callback_url and we can close this window.
  if(array_key_exists("in_popup", $_GET)) {
    close_popup();
    exit;
  }

  // if a session is initialized, fetch the user's profile information
  if($session) {
    // Get the currently sessioned user.
    $user = $session->getSessionedUser();

    // Load the profile for the current user.
    $profile = $user->getProfile();
    $profile_contacts=XmltoArray($user->getContactSync());
   $contacts=array();
   foreach($profile_contacts['contactsync']['contacts'] as $key=>$profileContact){
       foreach($profileContact['fields'] as $contact){
          $contacts[$key][$contact['type']]=$contact['value'];
       }
   }
  // echo "<pre/>";
  // print_r($contacts);exit;

  }
}
//echo "<pre />";
//print_r($_SESSION);exit;
/**
 * Helper method to close the pop-up window via javascript.
 */
function close_popup() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.close();
</script>
<?php
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Get the contact list from Yahoo-Idiot Minds</title>
<style type="text/css">
body{
background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
.yh_frnds{
    list-style:none;
}
.yh_frnds li{
    padding:10px;
    float:left;
    width:30%;
}
.frnd_list{
    margin-top:-25px;
    margin-left:40px;
}
.fb_frnds a{
        text-decoration:none;
         background: #333;
         filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#333', endColorstr='#D95858'); /* for IE */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#333), to(#D95858)); /* for webkit browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #333,  #D95858)/* for firefox 3.6+ */ ;
    color: #FFFFFF;
        float: right;
        font: bold 13px arial;
        margin-right:110px ;


}
</style>

    <!-- Combo-handled YUI JS files: -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="yahoo-dom-event.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popupmanager.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      if($hasSession == FALSE) { 
        // if a session does not exist, output the
        // login / share button linked to the auth_url.
        ?>  
       <a href="<?php echo $auth_url; ?>" id="yloginLink"><img src="yahoo-oauth-connect.png" style="width:150px;margin-left: 350px;" title="Get the contact list from Yahoo-Idiot Minds" alt="Get the contact list from Yahoo-Idiot Minds" /></a>
    <?php  }
      else if($hasSession && $profile) {  

        // if a session does exist and the profile data was
        // fetched without error, print out a simple usercard.
       ?>
      <img src="<?php echo $profile->image->imageUrl; ?>" style="width:10%;" />
      <h2>Hi <a href="<?php echo $profile->profileUrl; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $profile->nickname; ?></a>
      </h2>

<?php
        if($profile->status->message != "") {
          $statusDate = date('F j, y, g:i a', strtotime($profile->status->lastStatusModified));
          echo sprintf("<p><strong>&#8220;</strong>%s<strong>&#8221;</strong> on %s</p>", $profile->status->message, $statusDate);
        }

        echo "<p><a href=\"?logout\">Logout</a></p>"; ?>

        <ul  class="yh_frnds">
<?php
    foreach($contacts as $user_friend){

     if(isset($user_friend['email'])){
?>
<li ><img src="yahoo1.png" width="30" height="30"/>
<div  class="frnd_list"><strong><?php echo $user_friend['name']['givenName']; ?></strong><br /><?php echo $user_friend['email'];?></div>
</li>

<?php }
 }  ?>
</ul>
 <?php     }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var Event = YAHOO.util.Event;
      var _gel = function(el) {return document.getElementById(el)};

      function handleDOMReady() {
        if(_gel("yloginLink")) {
          Event.addListener("yloginLink", "click", handleLoginClick);
        }
      }

      function handleLoginClick(event) {
        // block the url from opening like normal
        Event.preventDefault(event);

        // open pop-up using the auth_url
        var auth_url = _gel("yloginLink").href;
        PopupManager.open(auth_url,600,435);
      }

      Event.onDOMReady(handleDOMReady);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because the function "YahooSession::createAuthorizationUrl" returns NULL or FALSE? You should make sure, that your params are okay and valid. May you would recive the correct auth_url

Comment: But I've tried it by giving direct callback url, it is still not working

Comment: What do you mean with "giving direct callback url"? Can you add this into your previous post?

Comment: blank? or completely unset? Because it only gets set if $hasSession is non-false.

Comment: Ah wait, here we go! You first check, if hasSession - and it's FALSE. And if it is false, you start the YahooSession::createAuthorizationUrl - but after that, hasSession is still false, because you never re-checked.

Comment: I just know whenever it is passed to the link it generates the same window by popping it up rather than going to callback. May be it is because $auth_url is getting no value @marc

Comment: Yeah sure. Let me know.

Comment: Yes you are right but what should I do with this regards? @Tyralcori

Comment: @Mandeep may you can look at my answer - there is the modified / added line. Let me know, if this works

Answer (score 0):

You never changed the "hasSession" needle. Imagine: You check, if the user has an active session. If you have no active session, you auth yourself by using same service. But after that login - you never re-check the session / or update the "hasSession" needle. Use the following code:

( Search for @Tyralcori for finding my changes)

```
//for converting xml to array
function XmltoArray($xml) {
    $array = json_decode(json_encode($xml), TRUE);

    foreach ( array_slice($array, 0) as $key => $value ) {
        if ( empty($value) ) $array[$key] = NULL;
        elseif ( is_array($value) ) $array[$key] = XmltoArray($value);
    }

    return $array;
    }

// debug settings
//error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE); # do not show notices as library is php4 compatable
//ini_set('display_errors', true);
YahooLogger::setDebug(true);
YahooLogger::setDebugDestination('LOG');

// use memcache to store oauth credentials via php native sessions
//ini_set('session.save_handler', 'files');
//session_save_path('/tmp/');
session_start();

// Make sure you obtain application keys before continuing by visiting:
// https://developer.yahoo.com/dashboard/createKey.html

define('OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY', '****');
define('OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET', '****');
define('OAUTH_DOMAIN', '*****');
define('OAUTH_APP_ID', '****');

if(array_key_exists("logout", $_GET)) {
  // if a session exists and the logout flag is detected
  // clear the session tokens and reload the page.
  YahooSession::clearSession();
  header("Location: index.php");
}

// check for the existance of a session.
// this will determine if we need to show a pop-up and fetch the auth url,
// or fetch the user's social data.
$hasSession = YahooSession::hasSession(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_APP_ID);

if($hasSession == FALSE) {
  // create the callback url,
  $callback = YahooUtil::current_url()."?in_popup";
  $sessionStore = new NativeSessionStore();
  // pass the credentials to get an auth url.
  // this URL will be used for the pop-up.
  $auth_url = YahooSession::createAuthorizationUrl(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, $callback, $sessionStore);

  // @Tyralcori Changes: RE-Check the session after authorization
      $hasSession = YahooSession::hasSession(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_APP_ID);
}
else {
  // pass the credentials to initiate a session
  $session = YahooSession::requireSession(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_APP_ID);

  // if the in_popup flag is detected,
  // the pop-up has loaded the callback_url and we can close this window.
  if(array_key_exists("in_popup", $_GET)) {
    close_popup();
    exit;
  }

  // if a session is initialized, fetch the user's profile information
  if($session) {
    // Get the currently sessioned user.
    $user = $session->getSessionedUser();

    // Load the profile for the current user.
    $profile = $user->getProfile();
    $profile_contacts=XmltoArray($user->getContactSync());
   $contacts=array();
   foreach($profile_contacts['contactsync']['contacts'] as $key=>$profileContact){
       foreach($profileContact['fields'] as $contact){
      $contacts[$key][$contact['type']]=$contact['value'];
       }
   }
  // echo "<pre/>";
  // print_r($contacts);exit;

  }
}
//echo "<pre />";
//print_r($_SESSION);exit;
/**
 * Helper method to close the pop-up window via javascript.
 */
function close_popup() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.close();
</script>
<?php
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Get the contact list from Yahoo-Idiot Minds</title>
<style type="text/css">
body{
background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
.yh_frnds{
    list-style:none;
}
.yh_frnds li{
    padding:10px;
    float:left;
    width:30%;
}
.frnd_list{
    margin-top:-25px;
    margin-left:40px;
}
.fb_frnds a{
    text-decoration:none;
     background: #333;
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#333', endColorstr='#D95858'); /* for IE */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#333), to(#D95858)); /* for webkit browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #333,  #D95858)/* for firefox 3.6+ */ ;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
    font: bold 13px arial;
    margin-right:110px ;


}
</style>

    <!-- Combo-handled YUI JS files: -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="yahoo-dom-event.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popupmanager.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      if($hasSession == FALSE) { 
    // if a session does not exist, output the
    // login / share button linked to the auth_url.
    ?>  
       <a href="<?php echo $auth_url; ?>" id="yloginLink"><img src="yahoo-oauth-connect.png" style="width:150px;margin-left: 350px;" title="Get the contact list from Yahoo-Idiot Minds" alt="Get the contact list from Yahoo-Idiot Minds" /></a>
    <?php  }
      else if($hasSession && $profile) {  

    // if a session does exist and the profile data was
    // fetched without error, print out a simple usercard.
       ?>
      <img src="<?php echo $profile->image->imageUrl; ?>" style="width:10%;" />
      <h2>Hi <a href="<?php echo $profile->profileUrl; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $profile->nickname; ?></a>
      </h2>

<?php
    if($profile->status->message != "") {
      $statusDate = date('F j, y, g:i a', strtotime($profile->status->lastStatusModified));
      echo sprintf("<p><strong>&#8220;</strong>%s<strong>&#8221;</strong> on %s</p>", $profile->status->message, $statusDate);
    }

    echo "<p><a href=\"?logout\">Logout</a></p>"; ?>

    <ul  class="yh_frnds">
<?php
    foreach($contacts as $user_friend){

     if(isset($user_friend['email'])){
?>
<li ><img src="yahoo1.png" width="30" height="30"/>
<div  class="frnd_list"><strong><?php echo $user_friend['name']['givenName']; ?></strong><br /><?php echo $user_friend['email'];?></div>
</li>

<?php }
 }  ?>
</ul>
 <?php     }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var Event = YAHOO.util.Event;
      var _gel = function(el) {return document.getElementById(el)};

      function handleDOMReady() {
    if(_gel("yloginLink")) {
      Event.addListener("yloginLink", "click", handleLoginClick);
    }
      }

      function handleLoginClick(event) {
    // block the url from opening like normal
    Event.preventDefault(event);

    // open pop-up using the auth_url
    var auth_url = _gel("yloginLink").href;
    PopupManager.open(auth_url,600,435);
      }

      Event.onDOMReady(handleDOMReady);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Tyracori for your help but it is still having the same problem :( .

Comment: Could you dump the second "$hasSession" to check the value inside? I expect, it's empty

Comment: Yeah It is still empty @Tyralcori

Comment: Maybe, because the credentials are not valid? And that's why the function "YahooSession::createAuthorizationUrl()" return false. Or is `$auth_url` given / filled?

Comment: okay I'll try it and providing different credentials, if it works! @Tyracori

Comment: It is still not working :(, I've tried changing credentials as well

Comment: But the "auth_url" is filled?

Comment: Nopes it is still creating the same problem